# Поиск дубликатов файлов

Tags: c++

Помогите написать в Visual Studio консольное приложение:

1. просим директорию
2. пробегаем по всем файлам (папкам с файлами) в указанной в п.1 директории
3. добавляем каждый файл в структуру (`name, saiz, address`) // имя.расширение файла, размер, путь к нему
4. сортируем элементы структуры по `имя`
5. проверяем каждый элемент по очереди со следующими до первого несовпадения по имени (элементы с одинаковыми именами проверяем по размеру) // находим дубликаты
6. выводим на экран дубликаты // адрес 1, адрес 2, размер дубликатов

Помощь очень нужна... сам программировать ещё не научился, умею пока только думать)

Comment: А если сказать правду, то препод дал  задание нужно решить.
так как для человека далеким от программирования Ваш 3 пункт будет загадкой.

Начинайте писать сами , а вот если что то не получиться тогда просите помощи, а за Вас делать ни кто не будет.

Comment: Да, кстати, а как в Си++ открыть папку и узнать её содержимое?

Answer (score 5):

Древнейший способ просмотреть каталог: использовать _findfirst, _findnext из "io.h"

В цикле проверяем заданный каталог, каждый найденный элемент проверяем на предмет наличия в атрибутах бита _A_SUBDIR, если да - проходим рекурсивно в этот подкаталог

```
#include <io.h>

void listdir(char *root) {
_finddata_t fd;
int rc;
long hFile;
char mask[260];
char subdir[260];

sprintf(mask, "%s\\*.*", root);

for( rc = (hFile = _findfirst(mask, &fd)); rc != -1; rc = _findnext(hFile, &fd) ) {
    if ( fd.name[0] != '.' ) {
        printf("\n%s\\%s", root, fd.name);
        if ( fd.attrib & _A_SUBDIR ) {
            sprintf(subdir, "%s\\%s", root, fd.name);
            listdir(subdir);
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
int main() {
char root[260] = "d:\\temp";
listdir(root);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Я не знал, а теперь буду использовать =) Спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо! а как теперь каждый файл занести в структуру (имя размер адрес?)

Comment: Попробуйте сами. А то если вам на это ответят, то следующим вопросом будет "как отсортировать". А оценку за лабу в итоге получите вы, а не @renegator.

Comment: Ну тут уж совсем просто. Имя лежит в fd.name, размер в fd.size, путь - это значение root

Answer (score 0):

А зачем сортировать ?

Сделайте хэш-таблицу по именам файлов, каждый элемент - заголовок списка из Ваших структур (size, attr, path ...). Поместили в таблицу все файлы.

Пробежались по ней, печатаете из списков размером 2 и более. Только с синонимами (по хэш-коду) аккуратно разберитесь, если все синонимы класть в один список.

Будет быстрее, чем с сортировкой.

Comment: мне на надо скорость))) мне надо любую чтобы работала...)

Comment: Тогда самое простое (и медленное). 

Читаете все файлы в массив (по мере необходимости realloc() его). Поочередно берете элементы массива и сравниваете со всеми от следующего до конца массива. Нашли дубликат - напечатали **и вычеркнули** (например первый байт имени обнулили).

Все. (Код сами напишите ?)

Comment: Тупо со следующим не будет работать, подряд могут идти несколько одинаковых. Все равно вложенный цикл делать. 

Сортировку (если думаете все же ней делать) сами **пока не пишите**. Использйте qsort(). (См. man qsort).

Comment: Разбейте задачу на четко выделенные части (они станут функциями в Вашей программе). По каждой части (если за денек не решите сами) формулируйте конкретный вопрос. Лучше попытайтесь все же что-то сделать, а потом спрашивайте, приводите куски кода и в чем проблема (что хотели увидеть, а что видите). Ну, в таком духе.


Это мой последний комментарий здесь (Лимит-с).